# Can't loop to create new instances of Clipboard.js Buttons

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I'm currently using Clipboard.js to copy text from textareas. I have multiple textareas that I would like to copy from each with their respective copy buttons.

I'm able to get this to work with the following button setup code:

```
new Clipboard(EXAMPLE_EDITORS[0][1], {
    text: function (trigger) {
        return $(EXAMPLE_EDITORS[0][0]).html();
    }
});

new Clipboard(EXAMPLE_EDITORS[1][1], {
    text: function (trigger) {
        return $(EXAMPLE_EDITORS[1][0]).html();
    }
});

new Clipboard(EXAMPLE_EDITORS[2][1], {
    text: function (trigger) {
        return $(EXAMPLE_EDITORS[2][0]).html();
    }
});
... // And so on for N number of buttons.
```

Given this, I was trying to loop to create the buttons. However, simply looping as follows didn't work out:

```
BUTTONS = [];
var example_editor_count;
for (example_editor_count = 0; example_editor_count < EXAMPLE_EDITORS.length; example_editor_count++) {
    BUTTONS.push( new Clipboard(EXAMPLE_EDITORS[example_editor_count][1], {
        text: function (trigger) {
            return $(EXAMPLE_EDITORS[example_editor_count][0]).html();
        }
    }) );
}
```

Instead of pushing to an empty list, I also tried pre-allocating an array of EXAMPLE_EDITORS.length and iterating over this array.

This didn't work either.

**My ultimate question**: why does the button copy only when hard coded like the first code sample but not when looped over?

Thanks